# Strange tooltip positioning on the site analytics page

Tags: bug, tooltips, graphs, site-analytics

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics

> [image]

I guess, the tooltip should appear near the cursor.

**Spec:** Win7 (64-bit), Firefox 65.0.1 (64-bit).

Comment: Repro-ed here on MSE as well, although on my setup (chrome, win10) the label is way down, not to the right. I'm zoomed on 100% in case that is believed to be an issue.

Comment: I think [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380261/when-building-a-custom-view-the-tag-autocomplete-widget-position-looks-wrong)...